# Mass import user from CSV into FE users table

Tags: typo3

Is there a extension for Typo3 with which I can import frontend user data into the backend?

I searched the internet and all extensions I found were for old versions of Typo3 (I'm using 4.5) or not in the repository any more.

Answer (score 1):

The direct mail extension is able to do so and you could even do it via phpMyAdmin i guess (never tried). If you need to do it on regular/automatic basis have a look at [external_import](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/external_import)

Comment: Before I go in depth into external_import reading: I see that is a "import all if you know what to do" extension. Is it possible with this extension, to make a 'template' for the export. Say. One user has the right to upload a csv and I prepare the task, so that nothing can be corrupted?

Comment: Directmail probably imports to tt_address and not as fe users. I wonder if there is a way to translate one from the other though.

Comment: For security reasons it is highly recommended to use hashed and salted user passwords. With this in place it will not be possible to use phpMyAdmin or some simple database import extension as all passwords have to be encrypted before being written into the db.